# BigQuery Scheduled Query not Appending

Tags: google-bigquery

I have scheduled query to refresh an existing BQ table.
BQ says the job runs, and confirms the time it finished.

However, the rows never actually get appended.

There are no sorts of errors or anything firing.

The table even says it was last modified at the same time that the scheduled query runs.

The write type is write append.

Anyone experience this issue?
Thank you

Comment: Can you try doing `bq ls -j --all` from the command line? That will list all recent jobs, and you can check the status of them.

Comment: If you give us more details, I can try to set up a similar scenario to check... but we'll need more details